# Google Chrome Does Not Load H264 Decoders when being started with startx on boot

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, google-chrome, x11, xorg

I am trying to launch google chrome via startx on boot with systemd to create an [Ubuntu 16.04 browser kiosk](https://thepcspy.com/read/building-a-kiosk-computer-ubuntu-1404-chrome/). Everything works great, except I am unable to play any videos in the browser.

When I log into the user on the device and force launch chrome with startx videos do play, but if I close that session and relaunch it, videos stop working.

I also tried running startx with chromium and firefox with the appropriate codecs installed. The same behavior occurs. When logging into the user and running `startx google-chrome`, `startx chromium`, or `startx firefox` the first time running startx videos will work. When I close that Xsession, any subsequent application running a new startx X session seems to be unable to play videos.

I am running Ubuntu without any GUI on boot, just the terminal.

Is there something I need to run when starting an X server for codecs to be recognized?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could try to launch xterm instead of chrome. Then run chrome from xterm and see if it outputs any errors to stdout/stderr.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I tried that. The first time I ran chrome from xterm, video worked, but an error was logged to the console, `[<date>:ERROR:ffmpeg_demuxer.cc(1510)] OnReadFrameDone result=-541478725 IsMaxMemoryUsageReached=0`. I then quit chrome (but not xterm) and re-ran chrome. This time there was no ffmpeg error, but video wasn't working.